# How to acheive a "stolen_at" field which is populated when the "status" field is updated? TRIGGER function and GENERATED ALWAYS AS attempts attached

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, postgresql-triggers

How to update `stolen_at` such that it is populated with the current timestamp when `status` is updated from `INSTOCK` to `STOLEN`?

I've attempted a trigger based approached but it contains a bug:

```
SQL Error [2F005]: ERROR: control reached end of trigger procedure without RETURN
  Where: PL/pgSQL function stolen()
```

The trigger approach:

```
CREATE TABLE items ( 
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    item_name text NOT NULL, 
    item_status text NOT NULL, 
    stolen_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME zone 
);


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION stolen() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $CODE$ 
BEGIN
   -- Populate stolen_at with datetime only if item_status 
   -- changes from INSTOCK to STOLEN
   IF NEW.item_status = 'STOLEN' 
   AND OLD.item_status = 'INSTOCK' 
   THEN
      NEW.stolen_at : = now() AT TIME zone 'utc';
   END IF;
END $CODE$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER populate_stoken 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF item_status 
ON items FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE stolen();
```

The other approach explored was a function which takes in the `id` and `new_item_status` and populates the `item_status` field. I could not get it to work though:

```
CREATE TABLE items ( 
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    item_name text NOT NULL, 
    item_status text NOT NULL, 
    stolen_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME zone NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS (stolen2(id, item_status)) STORED 
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION stolen2(id INT, new_item_status text) RETURNS TIMESTAMP AS $CODE$ 
DECLARE stolen_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME zone;
BEGIN
   SELECT
      * 
   FROM
      items 
   WHERE
      id = id 
      AND item_status = 'INSTOCK';      
      
   -- Return if conditions satisfy otherwise return null 
   IF found AND new_item_status = 'STOLEN' 
   THEN
      RETURN now() AT TIME zone 'utc';
   ELSE
      RETURN NULL;
END IF;
END $CODE$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Which of the two approaches is preferred (e.g. less resource intensive) and what is the correct way to implement them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first trigger is almost fine, but two things are wrong:

- it has to be a `BEFORE` trigger so that you can modify the new row
- you are missing `RETURN NEW;` right before the final `END;` (see [here](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/what-to-return-from-a-postgresql-row-level-trigger/) for a discussion)

Comment: Thank you for that! What's your view on using triggers vs generated as using functions (wish a select inside the function) to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Generated columns won't wor in this case.